# Prevent one code from executing when you click on another element in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the code, in js, I have two onclick events one to do when td in the table was a click and the other to do when elements(.eb_edit) inside this td was clicked.

And I want the code responsible for td not to execute when clicking on this element(.eb_edit) which is inside it.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.eb_edit', function() {
    fetch_data_selected_update($('#konto_select').val(), $(this).attr('update_id'));
});

$(document).on('click', 'td', function() {
    fetch_data_selected_insert($('#konto_select').val(), $(this).attr('day'));
});
```

By clicking on td, the page loads once more only with new popover to add the event in this day, and when we click on the element we load the page with new popover to edit it.

Of course, I can create a page with a popover for each day and for each item, but the page loads too long, so that's not a solution. I prefer to create elements dynamically when clicking on the element using ajax.

I hope you understand, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this using `stopPropagation` , this would stop the parent listeners from execution when an event occurs on the child element

```
$(document).on('click', '.eb_edit', function(event) {
   fetch_data_selected_update($('#konto_select').val(), $(this).attr('update_id'));
   event.stopPropagation();

});
```

Take a look at [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/event-stoppropagation.htm)

Comment: Great, it was exactly what i was looking for, thanks